# Create a StringCharFeatures from bytes

Tags: python-3.x, shogun

I need to create a shogun `StringCharFeatures` from a list of strings containing non-ascii characters (e.g. "é").

In python 2 this works:

```
from modshogun import StringCharFeatures, RAWBYTE
StringCharFeatures([u"abcdé".encode('LATIN-1')], RAWBYTE)
```

but with python 3, it raises an exception:

```
NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_StringCharFeatures'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    shogun::CStringFeatures< char >::CStringFeatures()
    shogun::CStringFeatures< char >::CStringFeatures(shogun::EAlphabet)
    shogun::CStringFeatures< char >::CStringFeatures(shogun::SGStringList< char >,shogun::EAlphabet)
    shogun::CStringFeatures< char >::CStringFeatures(shogun::SGStringList< char >,shogun::CAlphabet *)
    shogun::CStringFeatures< char >::CStringFeatures(shogun::CAlphabet *)
    shogun::CStringFeatures< char >::CStringFeatures(shogun::CStringFeatures< char > const &)
    shogun::CStringFeatures< char >::CStringFeatures(shogun::CFile *,shogun::EAlphabet)
    shogun::CStringFeatures< char >::CStringFeatures(shogun::CFile *)
```

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that shogun is expected to run with Python 3.x?  Their configure page says "SHOGUN requires the standard linux utils like bash, grep, test, sed, cut, ldd, uname gcc g++ and cat python (debian package: python2.4 or python2.5) for the ./configure to work."  Do other things work?

Comment: It works if you pass it a list of unicode strings as long as there are only ascii characters. I assumed python 3 was supported as fedora as a `python3-shogun` package.

Comment: Are you saying that `StringCharFeatures([u"abcd"], RAWBYTE)` (literally passing a list of unicode) works or that `StringCharFeatures([b"abcd"], RAWBYTE)` (passing ascii-only bytes) works?  Does `python3-shogun` have any doc, particularly any python3 specific section? ||| The error message comes from shogun (as it should be TypeError). You might find it in the shogun python wrapper and see if the logic is in the wrapper or in the wrapped code.  It is possible that the python3 port of the wrapper has a bug.

Answer (score 0):

this should work with latest develop and the fix will be included 6.2.0